# how to scale a WCF service in such a scenario

Tags: wcf

I have an app which can track vehicles. Vehicles can change location, appear or disappear at any time. In order to be always up to date, every 3 seconds the app sends to the server the region that is currently visible on the map and the server responds with a list of vehicles which are in the specific area.

Problem: What happens when I have a database of 1000 vehicles and 10000 requests being sent to the server every 3 seconds? How would you solve this scalability issue with WCF?

Comment: Maybe check less often or send only diffs? How many vehicles change zone in 3 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple a thing to do

**On Client-Side**

As Joachim said, try to limit request from client-side. I am not sure that vehicule will move significally every 3 seconds. Eventually, try to combine positions and others informations in a batch.

**On Server-Side**

> Problem: What happens when I have a database of 1000 vehicles and
>   10000 requests being sent to the server every 3 seconds? How would you
>   solve this scalability issue with WCF?

The best way to answer this question is to do a load test. The results are very depending on your service implementation. If your request takes more than 1 sec, you will certainly have performance problems.

Your can also add a queue behind your service for handling request, and even deploy your service on many servers in order to dispatch requests between different servers.